# Custom fields in forms (React JS)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, sequelize.js

Hi everyone I have a query
I want to give custom fields on my form so users will be able to customize the forms.
Firstly how can I achieve this react js?
The second thing in the backend I am using nodes with pgsql with sequelize ORM
So I have created my model according to the DB schema
When a user adds any custom I want to update the model at run time so the data will select and insert
How can I achieve this? If anyone has any idea then please share it with me

Comment: first of all your title must give a summary of your need.
Secondly you must be specific in what you face as a problem. Provide some code if possible

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.